# Biblatex change citation style

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex and want to change the citation style to a format like this: (Joshi et al., 2016).

How can I do this? I know I have to change the "style" attribute. But which style do I have to choose to get the described one?

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=anyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you like with `authoryear` style and `\parencite` command, adding a comma in `\nameyeardelim`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
    @book{joshi,
        author = {J. Joshi and Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
        year = {2016},
        title = {The title},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear,
    sorting=anyt
    ]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
  
\begin{document}
 
Parencite \parencite{joshi}.
 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `nameyeardelim` is a context-senstive delimiter now, so `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` would be a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: @moewe I forgot `\addcomma` existed, corrected. Thank you!